Is エッチ "milder" than 変態 in Japanese?
While I don't doubt the expertise of Japanese-porn connosseurs about the difference between ecchi and hentai in English, I'm not fully convinced there is a comparable different between エッチ and 変態 in Japanese.
The Wikipedia article on Hentai has one small reference to The Anime Movie Guide that claims ecchi is "milder than hentai". This book is dated 1997, the time at which these two words became English with their synthetic meanings, which means its distinction may be for the English words rather than their Japanese etymons.
The opening paragraph to the article for Ecchi makes several unsourced claims about the Japanese usage of エッチ, concluding that "softer than エロ" and does not imply perversion like hentai (is this English or Japanese?). In my personal experience, Googling the keywords エッチシーン, エッチ漫画, エッチアニメ results in multiple hardcore graphic images, and the results are comparable if you replace エッチ with 変態 or エロ(い). Therefore, I'm not convinced that it's that much "softer" and that less perverse. Perhaps it's vaguer, broader, or more euphemistic in the same TikTok-youth-slang way SA is more euphemistic than sexual assault? There's a paragraph in the Ecchi article that seems to support this hyphothesis of mine, that エッチ is not so much "milder"/"softer", but more colloquial and slangy:

After the Second World War, in the 1950s, interest in hentai was renewed, and people would sometimes refer to it just by the first English letter, H (pronounced as エッチ, [eꜜttɕi]). In 1952, the magazine Shukan Asahi reported that a woman who was groped by a stranger in a movie theater reacted with "ara etchi yo" ("hey, that's perverse"). In this context, etchi should be understood as sexually forward and is synonymous to iyarashii (嫌らしい, dirty or disgusting) or sukebe (すけべ, a person with sex on the brain). From this, the word etchi started to branch off, and assume new connotations. In the 1960s, etchi started to be used by youth to refer to sex in general. By the 1980s, it was used to mean sex, as in the phrase etchi suru (to have sex).[6][12][13]

エッチ seems to have started out as euphemistic insult, and it bastardized 変態 into something that can be used flippantly by young people. Still, that does not mean it's "milder", just broader.
It's hard to glean connotation from Kenkyusha's biligual dictionary as well. The examples in the entry for エッチ seem more colloquial and slangy, while those for 変態 seem more serious and academic:
エッチ

エッチな話はやめて.　《口》 Watch your mouth. ｜ None of your smuttiness [dirty talk].
あの人エッチね.　He is a (terrible) lecher, isn't he! ｜ He's got a dirty mind, hasn't he? ｜ He's filthy-minded.
きゃー, エッチ! のぞかないでよ.　Don't look, you horrible lecher [filthy creep, dirty old man]!
～する have sex 《with…》.

変態

そんなことを口にすると周囲から変態扱いされかねないよ.　Talk about that sort of thing, and people around you will be bound to treat you as abnormal [a pervert]
変態心理学　abnormal psychology.
変態性欲　abnormal sexuality [sexual desire]; sexual perversion.

My current reading of all this information is this:

変態 is originally a serious academic term. One of its literal meanings is "strange condition", hence "abnormality" (the other literal meaning, "to change conditions", whence "to transform" and "to metamorphose", isn't relevant here). It's famously used in the sexological phrase 変態性欲 "perverse sexual desire".
変態性欲 was shortened back to just 変態. 変態 acquired a new meaning, "sexually perverse".
変態 was further euphemized to just H, read as エッチ, in probably the same fashion that TikTokers these days shorten problematic words to R or SA.
エッチ was further semantically bleached, and its meanings are now diluted to just the vague notion of "sex".
English commentators on Japanese porno media misinterpreted the vagueness of エッチ as "mildness", and has perpetuated this misinterpretation ever since.

Is my reading correct? Or is エッチ indeed "milder" than 変態?

エッチ might refer to something "milder" than 変態, but their base meanings are so different today that it's meaningless to compare them on such an axis. There's indeed a long story about the etymology of エッチ, and how the meanings of these words have changed drastically after being borrowed into English as hentai/ecchi, but you seem to have already done good research on these.
As far as their contemporary usages in Japanese go, they're as follows:

変態 refers to any sexual behavior/interest that is considered abnormal (and often criminal), including stalking, public indecency, and extreme fetishism. It's also a derogatory term to refer to a person who has such interests. I don't think this term is inherently academic, but since it's at least not slang, it can be found in serious articles.
エッチ refers directly to sexual activities or content. When used as a noun or a suru-verb, it's one of the (slightly dated) ways to refer to sexual intercourse. When used as an adjective to describe a book or video, it refers to pornography or similar explicit content. When used as an adjective to describe a person, it means they are excessively sexually active or interested in sexual things.


I was surprised to hear that エッチ feels slightly dated. What's the normal way to refer to sex now? Just セックス? It's hard to imagine using that in ordinary conversation. But maybe I'm just getting old.

@どっかのおっさん If I remember correctly, the heyday of エッチ in this sense was around 1990. I think its place has been mainly taken not by direct terms such as セックス but by more indirect expressions such as する, やる, and 寝る.

@naruto Yes, and one can infer from the NDL Ngram Data that エッチ have truly become popular at the early 90s https://lab.ndl.go.jp/ngramviewer/?keyword=エッチ%2F変態&size=100&from=0&materialtype=full

Unfortunately this question cannot be truly answered without more good quality and easily accessible Japanese corpus, which is quite rare...  I wish to be corrected if I am wrong on this.
